# Insert default value in datetime column

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, for the data type `datetime`, can I insert like `"00-00-0000"` from the front end? It is giving an error. I want to insert `"00-00-0000"` if the user did not enter anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`00-00-0000` is not a date. If the user didn't enter anything, and that's ok, enter `NULL`. If you really want to show it as `00-00-0000` on the client side, you can do so using `COALESCE`, e.g.

```
DECLARE @d TABLE(d DATETIME);

INSERT @d SELECT '2011-01-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT NULL;

SELECT COALESCE(
  CONVERT(CHAR(10), d, 120), '0000-00-00')
  FROM @d;
```

Comment: Aaron thanks for reply, is it not possible from frent end, i am using asp.net.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not possible" - asp.net knows whether the user entered a date or not, doesn't it? And so can pass the keyword `NULL` instead of a formatted string?

Comment: Aaron actually, when user not enter date option then null will taken, but it is giving error, saying format is not correct, becuase i am converting the value which is in textbox into datetime.

Comment: You need to pass `NULL` with no quotes. You are never going to be able to store non-date strings like `'00-00-0000'` or `'NULL'` or `'be-fo-fart'` in a datetime column.